# What is the benefit of installing gunicorn for my django app on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I have recently switched to Django for a web app I'm developing and I followed the instructions at [Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) for getting a Django app running on Heroku.  I have a virtual environment in which my app is developed and I use git for version control and to push to Heroku. The link above suggests that I intall gunicorn:

> The examples above used the default HTTP server for Django. For
>   production apps, you may wish to use a more production-ready embedded
>   webserver, such as Tornado, gevent’s WSGI server, or Gunicorn.

They then walk the user through installing Gunicorn.

My question is: what problems might I run into if I skip this step and just stay with the default? What benefits will Gunicorn give me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gunicorn is production ready and really easy to use. I use it for my websites. You usually should run it via a reverse proxy like Nginx. I'm not sure what Heroku is using. You really should try it.

In my experience it's much easier to use and configure than apache & mod_wsgi, and the other similar setups.

**edit/update:**
As a summary of the comments below, Heroku already uses Nginx as a reverse proxy

Comment: Any chance you could briefly explain what a "reverse proxy" is / is used for?  What are the dangers if I don't use Nginx?

Comment: this [blog post](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2010/aug/16/lessons-learned-dash-easy-django-deployment/) is where I learned about gunicorn and nginx and got hooked. The reverse proxy protects you from certain types of denial of service attacks and nginx can also be used to very effectively host static files. When you put a ip and port number in you gunicorn configuration, is it your assigned IP or an internal ip (127.0.0.1)? Heroku maybe be doing some sort of proxy already. I have no idea how it works

Comment: this [post](http://www.quora.com/Scalability/How-does-Heroku-work) explains how heroku works, as far as the writer can figure out. It is already using Nginx reverse proxies

Comment: Wow, nice link.  Thank God for Quora.  I guess I won't worry about Nginx since I'm deploying on Heroku.

Comment: yup, but you should definitely use another HTTP server other than the default. So either gunicorn or one of the wsgi methods documented.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am trying to use gunicorn. I'll be posting on stack exchange again soon about why I can't see gunicorn running in my heroku logs...

Comment: it doesn't run until you use the `manage.py run_gunicorn` command, if that helps you troubleshoot

Comment: Ok, I see it running now.  I think that heroku automatically runs that command now that I have a procfile that contains the following line: <code>web: python myapp/manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3</code>

Comment: FYI - heroku does not use Nginx for Python.  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-faq#do_python_applications_run_behind_nginx

Comment: @Jody good find. But just to clarify the gunicorn wsgi service does. There shouldn't really be any pure python in an average Django project that would directly interact with the web.

Answer (score 7):

Much better performance, and probably better security and stability, too. Django's development web server (which is used by Heroku by default) isn't really designed to serve production applications.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try to set up my app to run gunicorn, in that case.  I hope this doesn't require me to start paying heroku, though, because I am still at the early stages of development.

Answer (score 1):

django's server, is a development server . It is light weigh and easy to use but should not be used in production because it is not production ready. it cannot handle many requests. This [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/django-server-comparison-the-development-server-mod_wsgi-uwsgi-and-gunicorn) offers a comparison between gunicorn, uwsgi and django's development server.